# ASP.Net MVC 3 Unity 2.0 IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am about to go live with an application I have built using ASP.Net MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1. For dependency injection I used the Unity 2.0 IoC. I used this tutorial as a guide to help setup the Unity IoC http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx

Today I was checking through my code for any last minute bug fixes and I came across the 
**Application_Start()** method in my **Global.asax file**. It looks something like this

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IControllerActivator, CustomControllerActivator>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IControllerActivator>());

        //container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork>());

        container.RegisterType<IListService, ListService>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IListService>());
        container.RegisterType<IShiftService, ShiftService>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IShiftService>());

}
```

The application is working fine, but I noticed I was missing the line of code

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Which goes after the line

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
```

As I say, my application was working fine (locally anyway) without this line of code. I have since added it and the application is again working as expected.

However, I am a bit worried that my Unity IoC wasn’t setup correctly. Why did my application work even without this additional line of code? And do I even need to add it?

Thanks for your help.

**Update**

Below shows the constructor for one of my Controllers

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IAccountService _accountService;
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IFormsAuthenticationService _formsService;
    private INotificationService _notifyService;
    private ILoggingService _logService;

    public AccountController(ILoggingService logService, IAccountService accountService, IUserService userService, IFormsAuthenticationService formsService, INotificationService notifyService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
        _userService = userService;
        _formsService = formsService;
        _notifyService = notifyService;
        _logService = logService;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the cosnstructor/s of one of your controllers?

Comment: Is that the only constructor you have for AccountController?

Comment: @Chandu Yes, I only have one Constructor for each of the Controllers in my code, ie, every Controller contains one single Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks

Please ignore this question. I found out that the line

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

was included in my code after all.

Note to self - look harder at your code next time!!!